# Taking user input from a method to use in another method in C#

Tags: c#

I need to prompt a user for an integer value of seconds in one method and then use that value in another method to convert to hours, minutes and seconds.  A third method needs to display the output.  I figured out how to convert the time, but I can't get my program to read the number of seconds that the user inputs from the first method to use in the second method.

I am completely new to programming (just a few weeks of experience).  Please keep that in mind with your answers.

Comment: Assuming its a console application try `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: @edrodriguez we were all there at one time, sadly stackoverflow was not there at that time :)

Comment: you should search online before you post a question here, this I can predict will be downvoted to oblivion

Comment: A quick Google search for something like "C# get user input" will likely be very helpful.  Don't think of this in terms of the *entire* application you're trying to write.  Think of each individual component separately.  Getting the input, converting it to a number, performing calculations, etc.  Take it one step at a time.  You won't find any ready-made examples of the exact application you want to write, but you will find examples of just about any piece of the application you want to write.

Answer (score 0):

We're assuming you're using a console application, if that's the case, just write the following:

```
 Console.Write("Input Seconds: ");
 string seconds = Console.ReadLine();
```

After that, `seconds` will be stored as a `string` so use this to change it into an `int` you can use for your operations:

```
 int s = Convert.ToInt32(seconds);
```